# 12 bit 2's complement of hexadecimal (0DE and EDA)

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, hex

I'm working on DPS310 pressure sensor using STM32F042F4P6, in which to calibrate the temperature, temperature coefficient is to be read (which is in 2's complement of 12 bit), I successfully read both the coefficient **c0: 0DE** and **c1: EDA**. (Refer page 14 of the DPS310 datasheet)
[Datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbtU2.png)

Now I need to take the 2's complement for further calculation, there's a ton of mess coming up in conversion, i.e if I convert c0 to binary and take 2's complement manually, answer comes around 3874 (decimals) but as 1 nibble is all 0, if I neglect it I get 34(decimals). While converting it from various websites give various other answers, I've tried AI as well but that made thing worse. If I convert 0DE to decimal and take 2's complement answer is different, if I do directly from hex answer is different. I knew the concept of 2's complement but I'm not sure which value to take into consideration.

(0DE)<sub>h</sub> = (0000 1101 1110)<sub>2</sub> ==> (1111 0010 0010)<sub>2</sub> = (3874)<sub>10</sub>

but below I've attached screenshot from various conversion:

**Website:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2UFx.png)
here the output is (0010 0010)<sub>2</sub> = (34)<sub>10</sub>

**ChatGPT:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klFBV.png)
here it gave me two answers (1422)<sub>10</sub> & (454)<sub>10</sub>

**Bing AI:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huvgx.png)
This gave answer as (598)<sub>10</sub>

**Bard (Google AI):**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBHoQ.png)
Which gave me (-1224)<sub>10</sub>

I'm pretty sure with the read hexadecimal value of coefficient c0 and c1, I verified with the default library of **Arduino**, there also hex value was 0DE and EDA respectively but there 2's complement of them are (**222**)<sub>10</sub> and (**-294**)<sub>10</sub> respectively. I've tried reading various posts and all I'm getting is more confused of the outcome, Can someone help me find the real answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very cautious about using AI Chatbots like ChatGPT and Google Bard. These are language models that are designed to produce human sounding text not accurate information. They are not mathematics or logic models.

Most architectures, including Arduino, use two's complement. **You do not need to convert it to two's complement. It's already stored that way** according to the docs you linked. You would only have to convert it if your architecture used something different. In that case, you would be converting FROM two's complement, not to it.

However, you do **need to do sign extension** because the bit length is different. The higher order bits will either start with all zeros or have garbage in them. For two's complement that means looking at the original most significant bit and copying it to all the higher order bits in the new storage location.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int extend12bit(int shorty)
{
        if (shorty & 0x800 ) //check MSB
                shorty = 0xFFFFF000 | shorty; //pad with 1s
        else
                shorty = 0x00000FFF & shorty; //pad with 0s
        return shorty;
}

void main()
{
        int foo = 0x0DE; //4 bytes = 32 bits
        foo = extend12bit(foo);
        printf("foo: %d\n",  foo);
        printf("foo physical: 0x%08X\n",  foo);

        int bar = 0xEDA;
        bar = extend12bit(bar);
        printf("bar %d\n",  bar);
        printf("bar physical: 0x%08X\n",  bar);
}
```

This produces the expected values and also shows how they are actually stored, endianness notwithstanding.

```
foo: 222
foo physical: 0x000000DE
bar -294
bar physical: 0xFFFFFEDA
```

Comment: @AnubhavShriwastava that looks right. Did you remember to do the scaling? 

Regarding "FROM two's complement" I'll update my post with some clarification when I have the time.